# Setting the output encoding to text/html for a given file ending in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, encoding

I would like to upload some HTML pages with the ending .aspx to our apache root server and I want apache to treat and deliver them just as regular .html files. I know this is unusual, but it is only for a preliminary site for SEO reasons until I get a windows server.

Right now when I view one of the files in my browser, the browser treats them as text/plain instead of text/html.

I already tried the following in my .htaccess file, but it did not seem to have any effect:

AddEncoding text/html .aspx

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: ask some interesting questions and you'll be upvoted in no time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what you're after is not only Content-Encoding but also Content-Type; try putting  [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) next to your AddEncoding:

```
AddType text/html .aspx
```

restart apache and check response headers.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much! I would upvote you, but that requires 15 points of reputation.